# How to handle zone offset changes in DB log search query if offset changes in fromTime and toTime

Tags: java, datetime, datetimeoffset, zoneddatetime

I have a situation where a query from User can come to search logs from 2 offsets (CET and CEST)

Eg: Search logs in DB, from 2019-09-20T12:00:00.000+01:00  to  2019-10-20T12:00:00.000+02:00.

Also I have the current Timezone offset from the user : +02:00.

Logs are stored in DB in UTC format. Now I can convert the fromtime and totime to UTC and search the logs

as below :

```
 DateTimeFormatter RFC_3339_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "Z")
            .optionalEnd()
            .toFormatter();

 String dateTimeString = "2019-09-20T12:00:00.000+01:00";
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.from(RFC_3339_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parse(dateTimeString)); 
  
    //Convert to UTC
    ZonedDateTime zoneDateTimeUtc = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    log.info(zoneDateTimeUtc.toString());
```

But the question how do show the datetime in response?

Easy Option :  Convert all logs to Current Offset of user (+02:00) and send.

But : This does not represent the correct information as some logs belong to older offset.

How to handle this situation? Pls let me know if any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the user will be happy to have the offset (+1 or +2) according to whether summer time (DST) is in effect for the time of year in question. Java knows time zones and summer time, and the conversion is straightforward when you know how:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Luxembourg");
    
    ZonedDateTime fromDatabase
            = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 5, 24, 23, 34, 45, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    ZonedDateTime forResponse = fromDatabase.withZoneSameInstant(zone);
    
    System.out.println(forResponse);
```

Output from the sample code is:

> 2020-05-25T01:34:45+02:00[Europe/Luxembourg]

Since I picked a date in the summer time part of the year (month of May), Java opted for offset +02:00 regardless of the fact that we are currently in standard time (+01:00).

I used Europe/Luxembourg as an example. CET and CEST are common names for a lot of time zones that share the offsets of +1 and +2 now, but have been different in history and may also be different in the future, for example when EU abandons summer time. So do pick the one that is most appropriate for your user.